# Apple.com's Search Stick that grows when clicked?

Tags: jquery, css, search

Would someone be able to point in the right direction for a "similar" jquery plug-in, for example, that could replicate apple's new search stick functionality?

When using Safari or Chrome, the search stick located in apple's global navigation will increase in size when clicked. I'd like to incorporate this same effect for a project of mine.

Link: http://www.apple.com/about/webbadges/

I appreciate your help!

Evan

Comment: "Safari or Chrome" means it's using webkit animations

Comment: Why ask for a plugin? This is a programming Q&A site so presumably you're a programmer and comfortable writing code, not just plugging in others'. The naive implementation of this is trivial... use animate(), increase the width and change the background color on click. One line of jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say just write it yourself! It isn't as hard as you might think. This might help get you started:

```
<html><body>

<style>
#search {
    background-color: #999;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    outline: none;
}
</style>

<input id="search" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#search').focus(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({ width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff' });
    }).blur(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({ width: '100px', backgroundColor: '#999' });
    });
});
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: @Mark - This is great! So, I created a demo with my code and your code here: http://jsbin.com/aruja3/ How can I have the background 'searchbga.gif' surrounding the field and the 'searchleftcap.gif' that borders left of the field animate with the field as well?

Comment: Sorry, very busy today. I'll have to look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks. I did my best with it in this new link and I appear to be closer, but it's not perfect. I appreciate your help! Thanks Mark. http://jsbin.com/aruja3/2/

Comment: @Evan - I'm looking at it right now. Please contact me at http://markeirich.com/contact so we can continue this discussion via e-mail.

Comment: @Evan - Okay, I've posted a new version including your images at http://jsfiddle.net/marke/GNF4T/ By the way, if you like my answer, it would be much appreciated if you marked it as Accepted ;-)

Comment: @Mark - That is really hot. Thank you so much for your help on this. This is definitely accepted. Again, thank you! :)

Comment: @Evan You're welcome. I've enjoyed figuring this out; it was a learning experience for me as well. :-)

Comment: @Mark - By the way, reviewing everything you did, I saw you rewrote basically everything and simplified all my CSS and form input junk. wow! Thank you! Very well done.

Answer (score 1):

animating the list of links should be easy as well

```
ul#menu {
display: table;
width: 500px;
}
ul#menu li {
display: table-cell;
}

<ul id=menu>
  <li>link1</li>
  <li>link2</li>
  <li>link3</li>
</ul>

$('#menu').animate({width:'-=100'},1000); //make them slimmer
$('#menu').animate({width:'+=100'},1000); //make them fatter
```